# Bind event to sub element from AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, ajax

To improve maintenability I'm trying to replace HTML that's being dynamically generated in script with AJAX query results. But there's rather uncommon problem to bind event handlers to dynamic content, although there's a lot of solution much of them work just partially. I mean that if I write

`$("#m" + event.PeerId).live("hover", function (args) {
  debugger;
}`

it works but

`$("#m" + event.PeerId + " sendMessage").live("click", function (args) {
  debugger;
}`

doesn't work, the event doesn't occurs if I click. Also I can trace hover event of the root downloaded element but I can't trace load, ready, etc. - they also never occur.

Tell me please how can I handle button click that is some subelement of the loaded content.

Comment: try $("#m" + event.PeerId").find("sendMessage").on("click");

Comment: @Vaibhav Katole: It's dynamically loaded content, so will not exist when this code is run. It needs a delegated event handler instead.

Comment: If the code below does not work, I will need to see an example of your HTML (or the rest of the related code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using any recent version of jQuery you should use a *delegated event handler*:

```
$(document).on("click", "#m" + event.PeerId + " sendMessage", function (args) {
     debugger;
});
```

If your ids all start with `m`, but the peerid is not know yet, use this:

```
$(document).on("click", "[id^=m] sendMessage", function (args) {
     debugger;
});
```

Delegated event handlers should be attached to a non-changing ancestor (`document` being the default if nothing closer to the changing elements is handy).

They work by listening for the event bubbling up the ancestors, to the one the handler is attached to, *then* applies the jQuery filter, *the* calls the function *for each matching element that caused the event*.

Note: Never use `'body'` for delegated event handlers as it has bugs relating to styling (which can cause events to not occur). Always use `document` if you do not have a closer element that does not change.

Comment: jQuery is 1.8.2 (from ASP 4 template provided with Visual Studio 2012). The code above as I've tried doesn't run event handler after button click. May be I need just to refresh jQuery?

Comment: It was added in jQuery 1.7: http://api.jquery.com/on/ I am missing a closing bracket is all. Have fixed :) If your PeerId values are generated at a later time, you can match on all of them with `$(document).on("click", [id^=m] sendMessage', function()...` ^= is a `startswith` selector (basically any id starting with `m`).

Comment: PeerId also will be required in the code of the handler. That's why I add handlers dynamically.

Comment: You can extract the peer id from the element instead. Extracting that value from the id attribute value should be easy as they are a fixed pattern e.g. `var peerid = $(this).closest('[id^m]').attr('id').substr(1)`. For more specific details you will need to show the rest of the related code.